React + Zustand instagram clone app. How to reset a global state that counts how many posts a user has
When i made my create post state that saves my users post to render on the UI i created an addPost function in the state that counts the posts to render below the users name on the profile page. Before i made the delete post function that deletes the count i tested the functionality of my code by creating a couple of posts and deleting them. Now when i created that function it works as planned but my state remembers two posts from before that haven't been deleted. I have 3 posts on my user but it shows 5. How do i reset my state?
I tried to make a function that resets my posts to an empty array and added that in my getUserPosts but the result was a really poor loading time of the profile page. This is the relevant code.
The state that counts posts :
import { create } from "zustand"

const useUserProfileStore = create((set) => ({
    userProfile: null,
    setUserProfile: (userProfile) => set({ userProfile }),
    //UPDATE the number of posts
    addPost: (post) => set(state => ({
        //Ubiti ono spreada postove usera i dodaje jos jedan id u post
        userProfile: { ...state.userProfile, posts: [post.id, ...state.userProfile.posts] }
    })),
    deletePost: (id) => set((state) => ({
        userProfile: {
            ...state.userProfile,
            posts: state.userProfile.posts.filter((post) => post.id !== id)
        }
    })),
}))

export default useUserProfileStore;

the hook that gets the posts and passes them onto components :
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import useShowToast from './useShowToast'
import usePostStore from '../store/postStore';
import useUserProfileStore from '../store/userProfileStore';
import { collection, getDocs, query, where } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { firestore } from '../Firebase/firebase';

const useGetUserPosts = () => {

    const showToast = useShowToast();
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const { posts, setPosts } = usePostStore();
    const userProfile = useUserProfileStore(state => state.userProfile);

    useEffect(() => {

        const getPosts = async () => {
            if (!userProfile) return
            setIsLoading(true);
            setPosts([]);

            try {

                const q = query(collection(firestore, "posts"), where("createdBy", "==", userProfile.uid))
                const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)

                const post = [];
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    post.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
                });

                //Sort by latest post (latest on top)
                post.sort((a, b) => b.createdAt - a.createdAt);
                setPosts(post);

            } catch (error) {

                showToast("Error", error.message, "error");
                setPosts([])

            } finally {

                setIsLoading(false);
            }
        }
        getPosts();
    }, [setPosts, userProfile, showToast])

    return { isLoading, posts }

}
export default useGetUserPosts;


It looks like the logic to filter based on ID may not be working properly, so that stale data is never being truly filtered out.
Can you try printing out both the id that gets passed into delete post and verify that that id also exists in the state.userProfile.posts list?
deletePost: (id) =>
set((state) => {
    console.log("Deleting post with id:", id);
    console.log("Posts before deletion:", state.userProfile.posts);
    const updatedPosts = state.userProfile.posts.filter((post) => post.id !== id);
    console.log("Posts after deletion:", updatedPosts);
    return {
        userProfile: {
            ...state.userProfile,
            posts: updatedPosts,
        },
    };
}),

Can you add in these print statements to tell me whether you see the proper IDs existing inside of state.userProfile.posts?

Okay so i wrote what you told me and now a new problem arose. Now when i delete the post the counter does not render the new count. it shows the new number only when i refresh the page. as for the console output. It logs the ID of the post we are trying to delete. then it logs that and the two rogues. and after deletion it logs the same 3 posts. even the one i am trying to delete

Fixed the render issue with this update :             const updatedPosts = state.userProfile.posts.filter((postId) => postId !== id);

Just now realised i can go into the firestore and delete the rogue posts by hand. Thanks anyways.
